# Pytest skip with parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

When using `pytest.mark.skip` with `pytest.mark.parametrize` python evaluates the `parametrize` parameters inspite of the `skip` function (obviously):

```py
import pytest

def get_params():
    # Do super heavy and slow logic to get parameters
    print("Params function called!")
    return (1, 2)

@pytest.mark.skip()
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b", [get_params()])
def test_foo(a, b):
    pass
```

In that example I always skip the `test_foo` test function, I got another function called `get_params` to get the parameters for the test function.
The `get_params` is very complicated and I don't want to call it if I know I'm going to skip the test.
If I run the test, I can see the print "Params function called!" meaning that the `get_params` function called.

I know this happens because of python evaluation order, and the `get_params` function called before the skip got to to its thing.
Because of that I have tried using generators:

```py
import pytest

def get_params():
    # Do super heavy and slow logic to get parameters
    print("Params function called!")
    return (1, 2)

def get_generator():
    yield get_params()

@pytest.mark.skip()
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b", get_generator())
def test_foo(a, b):
    pass
```

But the results are the same.
How can I make `get_params` function not to be called if `skip` was provided?

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible using the `mark.parametrize` marker, it is always evaluated. However, you can move the parametrization to the `pytest_generate_tests` hookimpl. Create a `conftest.py` file in your test or project root dir with the contents:

```
def get_params():
    ...


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # check if skip marker applied
    if metafunc.definition.get_closest_marker('skip') is not None:
        return
    # check if test requests a and b args
    if all(name in metafunc.definition.fixturenames for name in ('a', 'b')):
        metafunc.parametrize('a,b', [get_params()])
```

Any test requesting `a` and `b` args will now be parametrized if not skipped via marker.